# Is content of Mathematical Atlas still available somewhere?

Tags: online-resources

I have noticed that [Mathematical Atlas website](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/), which was maintained by Dave Rusin, no longer exists. (I am not sure how long ago this happened. The dates in the following paragraph suggest some time in 2015.) This site is referenced in [some posts on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=rusin%2Fknown-math%2F) and probably in [many comments](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rusin%20known-math%22%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com). You can find [a lot of websites, notes, papers, books referencing this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rusin+known-math%22). These facts suggest that it was a valuable resource with wealth of interesting information,

In the Wayback Machine this is [the most recent working version of Dave Rusin's homepage](http://web.archive.org/web/20150425161836/http://math.niu.edu/~rusin/) I was able to find.<sup>1</sup> This is the [last snapshot of working welcome page to Mathematical Atlas](http://web.archive.org/web/20150516025735/http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/) I found there.

I am sure that most (or maybe all) of the contents of this site can be find using Wayback Machine (a.k.a. Internet Archive). But still I want to ask:

- Is a complete mirror of this website available somewhere online?
- Has the website moved and is it now hosted on another host? (This seems unlikely to me, since if this was the case, I would expect some kind of information or at least a link at the old page.)

---

<sup>1</sup>EDIT: I did not notice that at the time of posting the question, but the last working snapshot of Dave Rusin's website is linking to http://www.math-atlas.org/welcome.html rather than
http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/ It seems that this new site has already [been up in 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20150417080205/http://www.math-atlas.org/welcome.html) and according to the answer posted to this question, there are plans to revive it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From sometime between December 2019 and January 2021 to sometime between January 2021 and September 2022 *The Mathematical Atlas* was available at http://www.math-atlas.org/.

When I first submitted this answer in May 2016, that Web site was unavailable. Per the comments under this question, the Web site went live again sometime between December 2019 and January 2021 and down again at some later point.

Comment: I probably should have figured this myself. (It is the first hit in Google when searching for [mathematical atlas](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematical+atlas).) But I guess it might be still useful that I asked this. It might help to get this information to other users of this site - and I personally consider it to be a useful information.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was the second link for me. ;)

Comment: 2016 has come and gone, and the same message is there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's also true in the later part of 2018...

Comment: @GerryMyerson it continues to be true at the end of 2019.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it seems that message was no longer there at the end of 2020 (now it being the start of 2021).

Comment: The website seems to be down once more…

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the archived version and would like to share it to you guys

http://amser.org/index.php?P=AMSER--ResourceFrame&resourceId=4131

The map is not working any more but you can still see the content by clicking the "Browse" link button

I haven't tested it too much, but seems to me that most of the links are working

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to find a browse link button any more on this page…